# TTF_RenderText_Solid error

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

im currently facing an strange error with rendering text using SDL_TTF and OpenGL.

The thing is that when i use ***TTF_RenderText_Blended*** , all texts are displayed good and without any problems

[image: Rendering text with TTF_RenderText_Blended]

But when i want switch to ***TTF_RenderText_Solid***  "buggy" black rectangles are displayed and i dont know specify if its problem with SDL_TTF or in OpenGL when creating the right texture from surface
[image: TTF_RenderText_Solid]

Function to load surface from textInfo(font,size)

```
void TextSprite::loadSprite(const std::string& text, textInfo* info){
SDL_Surface* tmpSurface = nullptr;

tmpSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(info->font,text.c_str(), *_color);
if (tmpSurface==nullptr){
    ErrorManager::systemError("Cannot make a text texture");
}
createTexture(tmpSurface);
```

}

Function to create an OpenGL texture from SDL_Surface

```
void TextSprite::createTexture(SDL_Surface* surface){
glGenTextures(1,&_textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,_textureID);

int Mode = GL_RGB;
if (surface->format->BytesPerPixel==4){
    Mode = GL_RGBA;
}
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,Mode,surface->w,surface->h,0,Mode,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,surface->pixels);

//Wrapping
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT);

//Filtering
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
_rect.w = surface->w;
_rect.h = surface->h;

SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
```

}

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TTF_RenderText_Solid()` outputs 8-bit palettized surfaces](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf_42.html#SEC42), not the 32-bit ARGB surfaces that `TextSprite::createTexture()` operates on.